# Cascading jQuery Image Fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src, onerror

I'm looking to dynamically load in an image:

```
<img data-src="test01">
```

And then use jQuery to take the data-src and then load in the image associated with that name, PLUS the extension. If THAT extension fails, then move onto the next extension, so on and so on until we get to the bottom when I just load in a default image. But I don't know how to check if there's an error AFTER I've set the image's `attr` once.  Here's the loop I have so far, and I'm getting ".error not a function"

```
$("img").each(function(){
     var newSource = $(this).data('src').toString();
     $(this).attr('src', 'images/'+newSource+'.gif').error(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/'+newSource+'.jpg').error(function(){
                $(this).attr('src', 'images/'+newSource+'.png').error(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src', 'images/default.jpg');
                });
            });
        });
});
```

The reason I'm doing this is because we have a database that holds the title of the image only, yet, over the years, different people have uploaded different image formats to the site, and we want to be able to load all of them on the page, sans extension, and then loop through each extension until we find a file that exists, and if not, default to a pre-set hard coded image URL

Comment: because we want to do this on the front end.

Comment: again, we want to perform this on the front end. I am not privvy to how complex the database that holds these images is. If your suggestions were possible, I am sure our back-end developers would have suggested that first.

Comment: Rather than changing the src repeatedly, why not perform like a quick HEAD ajax request for the image.  If you don't get a 404 or another error code, you know the url is valid, and **then** change the src.

Comment: @Taplar please submit your suggestion as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to do a HEAD request for the urls.  A benefit of a HEAD request is that it just tries to get headers for the endpoint, without trying to return data, so it can be super fast.  In your case, it could be a quick check to see if an image url is valid or not.

```js
function changeTheSrcIfTheUrlIsValid ( element, url ) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function(){
      //got a success response, set the src
      element.src = url;
    }
  });
}

$("img").each(function(){
  var img = this;
  var newSource = img.getAttribute('src');
  
  //check for a gif
  changeTheSrcIfTheUrlIsValid( img, 'images/'+ newSource +'.gif' )
    .then(null, function(){
      //error handler, try jpg next
      changeTheSrcIfTheUrlIsValid( img, 'images/'+ newSource +'.jpg' )
        .then(null, function(){
          //error handler, try png next
          changeTheSrcIfTheUrlIsValid( img, 'images/'+ newSource +'.png' )
            .then(null, function(){
              //error handler, use default
              img.src = 'images/default.jpg';
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use a Promise and a new Image() each time. The promise gets resolved or rejected in the onload  or onerror of the new Image.

Then there is a chain of `catch()` to try various extensions and finally set a default `noImageUrl` if all else fail

Something like:

```
function setImageSrc(src, ext, el){
   return new Promise(resolve, reject){
       var url = 'images/'+src+ ext;
       var img = new Image()
       img.src = url
       img.onerror = reject;
       img.onload = function(){
           el.src = url; // set src of current element in dom
           resolve(url)
       }
   }  
}



$("img").each(function(){
     var newSource = $(this).data('src').toString();
     var self = this
     setImageSrc(newSource, '.jpg', self)
        .catch(setImageSrc(newSource, '.png', self))
        .catch(setImageSrc(newSource, '.gif', self))
        .catch(function(){
            self.src = 'noImageUrl';           
        });

});
```